# Giving DataGridTextColumn a static value

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datagridcolumn, datagridtextcolumn

In WPF DataGrid, we can bind the DataGridTextColumn value this way.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn"
    Binding="{Binding MyColumnValue}" />
```

What if I wanted to give a static value for this column. Something like

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn"
    Value="This is a static text" />
```

I guess it's possible to use a converter, or add an additional property to binded model but I hope there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyColumn">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="This is a static text" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Or the set the source of the binding to a `string`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="MyColumn"
                    Binding="{Binding Source='This is a static text'}" />
```